# how to solve variable has no type declaration warning in flex / as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I came across this code snippet online that helps me solve a problem with a simple way to delay a piece of as3 code.

It runs fine and does the job, but I get a warning in flashbuilder / flex that says:

```
 variable 'delayTextVisible' has no type declaration.
```

here is the code snippet:

```
 var delayTextVisible = setInterval(showText,400);

     function showText():void {
      textgroup.visible = true;    // insert delayed code here
      clearInterval(delayTextVisible);    // stop setInterval repeating
     }
```

so my question is what type do I need to assign to the variable delayTextVisible for the warning to go away?  I tried :String but that didnt work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var delayTextVisible:uint = setInterval(showText,400);
```

`setInterval` return type is `uint`. see a documentation: [setInterval](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#setInterval%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

@bitmapdata.com's answer is correct.

However, in any case and for any variable, if you don't know its specific type, or if you need to declare the variable in a way that allows you to store many different types, you can always use the `*` placeholder:

```
var delayTextVisible:* = setInterval( showText, 400 );
```